# Change style of chapter title

Tags: chapters, report

I'm writing my thesis using document class `report`. The chapter titles are coming as "Chapter 1": a gap then on the next line "Introduction". I want to make it "1. Introduction". Can this be done?

I'm using the following code in my main tex file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\title{}
\author
    {}
        
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter*{Abstract}

\chapter{Introduction}
%\input{Chapters/Introduction}
...........
\chapter{Conclusion}
%\input{Chapters/Conclusion}
\chapter{Reference}
%\input{Chapters/Reference}

\end{document}
```

I would not like to change document class if possible, as I'm afraid that would create other formatting issues. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You can easily do that with the `titlesec` package and its `\titleformat` command. Unrelated: loading `inputenc` is no more necessary, as this has been the default that latex expects for more than 3 years.

Comment: Thank you! it was helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elaborating @Bernard comments, use `titlesec` package for formatting titles of chapters.

I give you a full example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,longtable}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

% I have added this
\usepackage[explicit,compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\bfseries\huge}{\filright\huge\thechapter.}{1ex}{\huge\filright #1}
    
\title{}
\author
    {}
        
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter*{Abstract}



\chapter{Introduction}
%\input{Chapters/Introduction}
...........
\chapter{Conclusion}
%\input{Chapters/Conclusion}
\chapter{Reference}
%\input{Chapters/Reference}

\end{document}
```

Here in the code:

```
% I have added this
\usepackage[explicit,compact]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
    {\bfseries\huge}{\filright\huge\thechapter.}{1ex}{\huge\filright #1}
```

`\huge` can change the font size.

`\filright` can change the orientation.

Comment: thanks. it helped

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helps by clicking Tick mark beside the answer.

Comment: @Jan3 The tick mark (tick sign) under like(up) and dislike(down) button.