# chapter title style and spacing issues of above of title

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec, chapter-page

I'm writing my thesis using document class report. The chapter titles are coming as "Chapter 1": a gap then on the next line "Introduction". I want to make it "Chapter 1: Introduction". Can this be done? first page of chapter how to minimize or maximize the space above of chapter title

Comment: Use either a package like [`titlesec`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) or more configurable class like [`scrreprt`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrreprt) or [`memoir`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir). If you need more help [than already available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/623814/277964), you should show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) that illustrates, what you've already tried.

Comment: BTW: I cannot see, how you question is related to the tags `fontspec` or `fontsize`. So I'll remove those.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.